# H264 data changing after serial communication in Python

Tags: python, camera, h.264

I am using Raspberry4 , i have USB camera module that have 2 device ports (video0 - Raw video , video2 - H264 video) . I using gstreamer pipeline as capture device

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-h264,width=640,height=480,framerate=10/1 ! x264enc ! h264parse ! videoconvert ! appsink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

I am reading frames from it , and writing to serial port.

In another device i am trying to read sent bytes , and convert them back to np array to use in cv2.imshow().

When i print received bytes and  bytes in sender code , i see that they are different (received bytes are changed , i see it when print np.array ) and i can not show received frame.

I surfed many sites looking for the answer, but couldn't .
What do you think about it?